# Can't see difference in suggested edited labelled 'language tag'; what to do?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits

I've reviewed two suggested edits this morning where the editor said 'language tag', and a whole block of code was marked as changed, but the original looked fine and the modified code looked the same as the original.  I am unwilling to approve a change just for the sake of change, so I've rejected those edits with a comment to the effect that I can't see any difference, but I don't like rejecting their efforts either.

- Is there a way to get at the markdown changes of a suggested edit?
- Is there a way to look at the original question or answer in markdown changes while there's an edit outstanding?
- Would it be possible to have a mechanism that allows us to see the markdown changes in the Suggested Edit review?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a Markdown diff button on the left-hand side of the suggested edit, in cases where the body of the post changed (titles and tags don't have Markdown to show the changes of):

[image: suggested edit interface in markdown comparison mode]

Of course, just because there was actually a change doesn't mean that it was [necessarily a valid one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131504/reason-behind-adding-language-hint-to-code).

I was kind of iffy on the suggestion in the above screenshot (one of the ones you had cast a reject vote on, it looks like), but I opted to approve it since I felt the change made that particular code block look marginally better. The other language tag-related edit you rejected was pointless, so rejection was the right call there regardless.

Comment: Oh - that's helpful.  Thank you.