# Reason behind adding language hint to code?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, language-hints

*Note, this is related to the question [Can't see difference in suggested edited labelled 'language tag'; what to do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131499/cant-see-difference-in-suggested-edited-labelled-language-tag-what-to-do), but none of the 
questions I have regarding it were answered in it....*

---

A [specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1154462/vyegorov) has suggested a large [number of edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1154462/vyegorov?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), on which he's added language hints to the code blocks in the post:

- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/257237
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/257236
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/257235

... etc.

But when looking at the posts he's edited, the syntax highlighting was already applied  to the code, *before* he added the language tag, so:

1. Why is he doing this?
2. Should I be rejecting the edits or not? (I assume so... it doesn't seem to be doing anything?)
3. Where's he got the idea to do this from?

Comment: The ones I approved seemed to have an incorrect syntax highlighting... and as the editor was making other improvements I ended up approving a few and improving ( rejecting ) those where no additional effort was made.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Reject them.** If the language identifier doesn't actually change anything in the post, it's completely useless and should be rejected as too minor (unless you're like me and actually type out a reason, which he'll likely never read).

I'm frankly happy to see that there are *some* people out there that **actually check** to see if the language identifier is necessary. Sometimes it's easy, like seeing `lang-php` and a [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag is an instant "duh, it's highlighted that way." Some of them require you to actually go to the post and check.

The ones you need to be careful of though are the [css](/questions/tagged/css) ones, because if they're also tagged [html](/questions/tagged/html), the HTML highlighting will override the CSS highlighting.

Comment: Yeah, I'm beginning to think that we need a non-diff rendered view for cases where it's hard to tell if the edit actually improved the display of the post. Can't remember if there's an existing request for that or not...

Comment: Re: highlighting of CSS questions, basically the `lang-css` hint is needed for CSS snippets *only*. No other hints are necessary. This applies whether or not the [html] tag is present, because both tags use `lang-default`. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121816/whats-happening-to-syntax-highlighting-for-css-questions and explore the links there to understand what's going on.

Comment: Another one that isn't auto-detected when other language tags are present is [tag:vb.net].

Comment: and if you have `PHP` and `MySQL` then everything is rendered [as PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10462365/458741)

Answer (score 7):

I'd say reject in most cases when that's the only change.

I've rejected a fair number of them today, where they didn't add anything - adding `lang-js` to the single code block of a question tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) doesn't provide any value, the syntax highlighting kicks in without the addition.

But be careful though: a few of them were indeed good (if a bit minor) on questions with blocks of code in different languages - and the edits did add some value there.

As for why he/she is doing this, and where he got that idea... I don't know.